# Laravel Singleton array not working, but works when using closure

Tags: php, laravel, singleton, inversion-of-control

In my `AppServiceProvider.php` I tried binding a singleton interface to a concrete class using the array syntax:

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public $singletons = [
        MyClassInterface::class => MyClass::class,
    ];
}
```

The interface is then typehinted in a class.

This gives an error like:

> TypeError: TheClassThatUsesTheService::__construct(): Argument #2 ($myClass) must be of type MyClassInterface, string given

The errors disspears if I make a manual singleton binding using a closure:

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind(MyClassInterface::class, function () {
            return new MyClass;
        });
    }
}
```

Should this not behave the same?

---

MyClass.php:

```
<?php

class MyClass extends Base implements MyClassInterface
{
    public function get(): mixed
    {
        //
    }

    public function insert(): void
    {
        //
    }
}
```

MyClassInterface.php:

```
<?php

interface MyClassInterface
{
    public function get(): mixed;
    public function insert(): void;
}
```

Base.php:

```
class Base
{
    protected function service()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share your MyClass implementation and its interface.

Comment: I have updated the question with the 2 files now

Comment: Also we need to know about your `Base` and the `__construct` of that

Comment: I have updated the qeustion with the Base class. It has no __construct.

Comment: Where do you use the singleton